# Using the input string "exit" to exit the program in Terminal

Tags: java, terminal, filewriter

I am writing a small little .jar application that asks user for a string and writes it into a `.txt` file. I am interested in the program keep executing the following instructions (that is, write date string, and write the input string into the text file) when the input string is not `exit`. My code does not work for that, ask it does not log the first line I input, nor the first `exit` I type. I tried a number of things, trying a `do-while` loop, but that didn't work. I wonder what the problem is?

```
try{
            String input = scanner();
            while(!input.equals("exit")){
                String fileLocation = "/Users/loop/Dropbox/goodTrance.txt";
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation,true);

                writer.append(returnDate()+": ");
                writer.append(input + "\n");

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                input = scanner();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

EDIT: `scanner()` is a static method that returns a scanner string. `returnDate()` returns today's date.

```
public static String returnDate(){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    }

public static String scanner(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String writeSomething = input.nextLine();
        return writeSomething;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your `scanner()` method.

Comment: What is scanner? A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does a call to `scanner()` do? It looks like you're calling it twice each time you loop, and may be discarding the first call (but checking it) and storing the 2nd call and not checking it. Methinks you should call it only *once* for each loop.

Note, your code has other problems:

- There's no need for the `scanner()` method.
- There's no need to keep re-creating a Scanner object, and in fact by doing so and not releasing resources, you run the risk of running out of resources.
- Instead create your Scanner *object* once, and use it inside of your try block, calling `nextLine()` on it as needed.
- Also consider closing your file *after the while loop, and in fact in the finally block of your try block. Close your Scanner *object* there as well.
- It's often a better idea to check your String with `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.
- It's safer to check it like so:

---

```
String line = null;
while ("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
  line = scanner.nextLine();
  // etc...
```

To avoid NPE

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft. Very amateur mistake I made. I declared it twice - no wonder.

Comment: I declared `String input = scanner();` outside of the while loop, and `input = scanner();` right before the end of the `for-loop`. Thanks!

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: see edits. You have other newbie problems in your code.

Comment: I put my changes above. How is that?

Comment: `finally{System.exit(0);}` is that what you mean?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: No. In the finally block, **close** the file by calling `close()` on it, and same with the Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a terminal connection which is sending the text? If that's the case the terminal protocol sends character by character which means you will not ever get the scanner().equals("exit") to true since it only takes one character and not a whole String.